# Theories/reasoning without a unique outcome

Tags: ambiguity

I'm looking for a better word than, eg "ambiguous" or "undecidable" to describe theories or reasoning processes that do not point to a unique outcome (or possibly, that cannot be proved).

Some colloquial expressions come close, eg "double edged sword", "cuts both ways", but these suggest binary outcomes rather than open-endedness.

Examples of situations that raise a suspicion that such a "state" exists as described in the title above, and that we need (or must in human experience have) a word for it, are:

1. Various aspects of CG Jung's theory of mind, where forces pointing in different directions can be identified, but how to assess or weigh them up, and what outcome may follow, cannot.
2. Various legal tests which specify a list of factors to be taken into account, but how these are to be assessed or weighed up, and what outcome may follow, is not prescribed.  The "fair use" doctrine in US copyright law is an example, but there are many others around the world.

Perhaps the answer is that these situations involve intuition rather than reasoning, but most experts who purport to apply reasoning in these kinds of circumstances would be offended by that suggestion.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The theory is 'incomplete'? Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_contracts

Comment: I'd call it guidance.

Comment: The fair use test isn't undecidable; it's just dependent on input. Copied an entire work so you could sell it for profit? Not fair use. Cited a single example as part of a college lesson? Fair use. Obviously there are harder cases, but that doesn't make the test itself undecidable. It's more like a mathematical function: "division" obviously doesn't have a unique outcome, and we do say that division *by zero* is undefined, but we don't say that division *itself* is undefined—and we certainly don't say that division is *ambiguous* or *undecidable* just because some cases are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer because it is not too easy to find.

The word you suggest, **undecidable**, has a stricter definition which is obviously appropriate:

> *undecidable* (adjective)
>
> (of a WFF) logically independent from the axioms of a given theory;
>   i.e., that it can never be either proved or disproved (i.e., have its
>   negation proved) on the basis of the axioms of the given theory.
>   (Note: this latter definition is independent of any time bounds or
>   computability issues, i.e., more Platonic.)

[[Synonyms.net](http://www.synonyms.net/synonym/undecidable)]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula), a well-formed formula (WFF) is defined:

> In mathematical logic, propositional logic and predicate logic, a
>   well-formed formula, abbreviated WFF or wff, often simply formula, is
>   a finite sequence of symbols from a given alphabet that is part of a
>   formal language.

[essentially, the problem can be stated!]

In a less rarefied register, **unresolvable** is available.

> *unresolvable*: not able to be resolved
>
> *an apparently unresolvable philosophical question*

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unresolvable)]

Answer (score 0):

debatable ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debatable))

> a : open to dispute
>   b : open to debate

unexplicit ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unexplicit))

> not explicit : lacking full and clear expression : vague ambiguous

open to interpretation ([Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-open-to-interpretation))

> if something is open to interpretation, its intended meaning is not clear and people may have different opinions about it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer on "undecidable", which I think comes closest to what I'm after.

"Indeterminate" is close (as are the other answers) - well known in law. But also connotes the issue of "opinion", ie in matters of opinion you can expect a range of outcomes, as opinions may reasonably differ.  Often applies to assessment or judgment on facts - not quite the same thing as undecidable.